# Xamarin android gui freezing when pausing seperate thread

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on a simple tic tac toe game using xamarin. I have also created a singleplayer mode where the CPU plays against you. the problem is that the CPU makes a move immediately after the player plays their move, so I want to add a delay and display "CPU is thinking" on the screen for about a second before executing the rest of the code. so I created a new thread

```
Thread animationThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(CPUAnimation))
            {
                IsBackground = true
            };
            animationThread.Start(infoText);
```

to do this as I don't want to use thread.sleep on the main thread obviously. this is the code for the method:

```
private static void CPUAnimation(object infTxt)
    {
        // Animation "CPU is thinking"

        TextView infoText = (TextView)infTxt;

        while (true)
        {
            if (cpuIsThinking)
            {
                infoText.Text = "CPU is thinking.";
                Thread.Sleep(333);
                infoText.Text = "CPU is thinking..";
                Thread.Sleep(333);
                infoText.Text = "CPU is thinking...";
                Thread.Sleep(333);
                cpuIsThinking = false;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }


    }
```

this is the code for one of the squares (buttons):

```
button1.Click += delegate
        {
            if (!(infoText.Text.EndsWith("wins!")) && !(infoText.Text.EndsWith(".")) && !cpuIsThinking && one == ' ')
            {
                one = 'X';
                button1.Text = "X";
                bool win = CheckPlayer(infoText);
                if (!win)
                {
                    cpuIsThinking = true;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (!cpuIsThinking)
                        {
                            int result = CPU(infoText, first);
                            CPUChoice(result, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9);
                            CheckCPU(infoText);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

but the gui freezes when I press any button and the app crashes with this error from visual studio:
`Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`
. I know I'm doing something wrong, since I don't have much experience with threads in C# or in general, really.
(quick note: the "infotext" that is passed through as a parameter is the textview I use to display any info to the player and I have to pass it through as I cant access it in any other way, as far as I know, so it would be great if someone could also tell me if there's a better way of doing this)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your views in UI thread, so just simply use `RunOnUiThread`, like so:

in activity: `RunOnUiThread(()=>infoText.Text = "CPU is thinking.");`

in fragment: `Activity.RunOnUiThread(()=>infoText.Text = "CPU is thinking.");`

Comment: i get an error: `an object reference is required for the non static field, method or property Activity.RunOnUiThread()`